# Adding a DLL project to VS2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012

I have some code that uses two Visual Studio projects. The first project relies on the second. The second is built as a DLL lib. Can I just add these two into a solution and then debug? Can I step through code in a DLL lib? If not how can I use the source from the DLL project in the first project?

Thanks

Comment: Yes to the first question. And yes to the second. Have you tried ? Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 2):

If your DLL projects compile with debugging information, then yes, you can use the Visual Studio debugger to debug their source. Note that any breakpoints you set will not be enabled until your DLL is loaded by the executable.

You can also use Visual Studio to debug DLL code without compiling your own executable. For example, if you are writing a plugin DLL for other software. In this case, you can set the 'Command' property in the 'Debugging' property pages to the executable that loads your DLL. When you start debugging, the executable will launch, and when it loads your DLL, you can start debugging it. Alternatively, you can just use the 'Attach to Process' debugging feature.

Comment: To be honest I would rather just use the source code rather than a DLL. So is it possible to do that? Or would I somehow have to integrate the source from the second into the first? These may sound like dumb questions but I am a hardware engineer trying to use some code to verify some hardware.

Comment: You would have to add the sources from your DLL into your executable project to do that, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. However, there will likely be other implications, eg. the DLL loading code (if dynamically loading DLLs), and any DLL import/export signatures in your headers.